# Why use of a frame pointer register is obsolete in ARM Procedure Call Standard?

Tags: pointers, arm, call, frame, procedure

I am reading the ARM procedure call standard:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/Cegbidie.html

It says:

> Only APCS variants that do not require a frame pointer register are supported. APCS variants that require a frame pointer register are obsolete. These variants are documented for backwards compatibility only.

Can someone tell me why? I thought one needs the frame pointer if the stack frame size is unknown at the compile time.

Comment: why would the stack frame size be unknown at compile time?  another reason for frame pointers is ease of programming (and debugging the compiler) and also sometimes just the way the instruction set works lends itself to one.  Not really needed for arm.

Comment: @dwelch Dynamically sized arrays on the stack would be one very obvious example.

Comment: can you provide some examples of this?

Comment: Examples, `int *p = alloca(var1); int var_arr[var2];`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the calling convention specifies how the stack gets cleaned up on function exit, you only need to have the stack pointer. The compiler can keep track of all the stack manipulation within the function, so there is no need to keep that information around in a separate register.

It certainly is convenient, but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Surely it's not so much for the benefit of the compiler - because as you say, it can track stack usage and undo it at the end of the function - but rather for debuggers which don't necessarily know the relationship been the current `sp` and the base of the current frame.

Comment: @Marko, the compiler can emit debug info for the debugger to do that.